# Is it possible to nest Mongoose methods?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  completed: Boolean,
  priority: String,
  dueDate: String
});

var ListSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [ItemSchema]

});
```

I want to reach an instance of the `ItemSchema`. Can I nest two Mongoose methods to reach it, like so:

```
router.route('/lists/:list_id/items/:items_id')
   .put(function(req, res) {
       List.findById(req.params.list_id, function(err, list) {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          }
          list.items.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.items_id, function(err, item) {
              if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            console.log(item);
            res.json(list);
            });`
```

Comment: Yes, it's not working.

Comment: To answer the question, yes it is possible to nest them.  However, what you are trying to do won't work.  As it stands,`list.items` is an array of ObjectIDs.  If you want to remove one, you'll have to do standard array manipulation, slice, splice, pop, whatever, to remove it from that list.  Then you would need to update the `list` object with the new items.  You may try doing a `populate` on the `List.findById` but I don't think that will make the `items` an array of documents, I think it just fills in the object.  You need the `items` to be an array of documents to get the update functions

Answer (score 0):

I found a much simpler solution to the problem using `.findById`, and then using the special `id` method for looking up a document by its `_id`. This doesn't answer whether you can nest Mongoose methods, but nonetheless a solution to accessing sub-documents within their parent.

[Mongoose Sub Document Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Here's the solution:

```
router.route('/lists/:list_id/items/:items_id')
.put(function(req, res) {
    List.findById(req.params.list_id, function(err, list) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }

      var item = list.items.id(req.params.items_id);
      item.completed = true;
      list.save(function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
              res.send(err);
          }
          res.json(result);
      })
  })
})
```